# Matlab - kpsstest

Tags: time-series, matlab, stationarity, kpss-test

If I have:

```
a=randn(100,1)
[h,p] = kpsstest(a,'lags',0:10)
```

why does the test fail to reject the nonstationarity hypothesis?

It gives back `h=0` while the process should be stationary by definition.

Did I misunderstand the usage of function `kpsstest`? I guess it should give back 1, for stationarity.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does the test fail to reject the nonstationarity hypothesis?

The null hypothesis of the KPSS test is that the series is stationary. And your example shows that the test correctly identifies a stationary series.

Comment: So the result h=0 means stationarity? Because if you see the documentation it.mathworks.com/help/econ/kpsstest.html for wages that are nonstationary they get h=0... I cannot understand how to read data. A p-value of 10% what does it mean? That with 10% we can say...?

Comment: @Klapaucius, If your chosen significance level is 5% and the p-value is larger than that (e.g. 0.10, or 10%), then you cannot reject the null hypothesis (which is that the series is stationary).

Comment: So if h=0 is stationary and if h=1 not-stationary. The pvalue is the one reported?

Comment: @Klapaucius, I don't understand you. What do you mean?

Comment: In the answer that matlab gives, how do I interpret h=0 or h=1?

Comment: $H_0$: stationarity, $H_1$: nonstationarity. If $p$-value < 0.05, reject $H_0$ in favour of $H_1$. If $p$-value $\geq$ 0.05, cannot reject $H_0$.

Comment: @Klapaucius, If my answer addresses your question in a satisfactory way, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer. That would indicate your problem is solved and the thread could be "finished".